# Slow Wi-Fi connection and login page redirect after renaming Tenda router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a Tenda brand wireless router that has started running slowly and started doing a strange login page redirect when you connect a wireless client. The problems seem to have started after I changed its name from Tenda-*something* (probably its factory-set name) to "grandma".

Now I'm having two problems with it:

1. After rebooting it, it performs normally/properly for about 30 seconds. But after about 30 seconds it goes back to being slow.
2. Now, when Wi-Fi clients join it, they are redirected to a router login page. You can still access everything on the Internet without signing into the router login page, but getting the router login page each time you rejoin the network is irritating and strange.

Any ideas what's causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: I'm afraid your English isn't quite good enough, so this question is very hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks you to read and help me to take a better question.

Comment: Okay, after your edit I was able to better understand what you were saying and I've edited your question to be a little more clear. By the way, can you post the exact model, hardware revision, and firmware version of the Tenda router you have? Can you quantify (measure and report) the speed you feel is proper (in the first 30 seconds) and the speed you feel is "slow" (after the first 30 seconds)? Can you post a screenshot of the router login page you get redirected to when you join? Did you look in the manual or user interface for any features related to login page redirects or captive portal?

Comment: In the first 30 sec (i didnt measured the download and upload speed but) i can watch youtube in 720p, after that (the 30sec), if i got a picture in messenger and i have to wait 1min to watch it , idk the problem but i tried something, i go to google search for cats and i have to wait 30 sec to see something, after that i got an idea, i write to chrome(192.168.0.1,router ip) and this is load in 2sec, and when i changed site on it this was fast so the lan is okay, like with every normal router, but if i want to do something on the wan (with the world) it is very slow.

Comment: And i have to say a very big sorry but i can't send you any picture because this router is at my friend's grandma, but if he goes to she, i"ll send that pictures to you, and the informations. And thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can remember to this question here is some photos to help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6lezYMvGBq8bEU0UHljUy1lZTg